# Explicit homeomorphism between an Infinite Cone and a one sheet hyperboloid

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

An infinite cone is given by the equation

$$B = \{(x,y,z) ∈ \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 −z^2 = 0\} $$

And a one sheeted hyperboliod is given by

$$C = \{(x,y,z) ∈ \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 −z^2 = 1\} $$

Are these two surfaces homeomorphic? And if yes, what are their explicit homeomorphisims?

I know both of these spaces are not compact, however I do not know how to check for other properties such as connectedness which are preserved under homeomorphisims.

Comment: Is there a point on the cone that looks different from any point on the hyperboloid?

Comment: Yes, I was considering the point (0,0,0) which does exist in B, but not in C, However, C is path connected and therefore connected, but B is not a collection of disjoint open subsets, therefore it is also connected. So, yes there are certain points on the cone that cannot exist on the hyperboloid, but under homeomorphism it shouldn't matter, because the mapping accomodates this.

Comment: @E.JHumphrey : There is only one point on the cone that has no neighborhoods homeomorphic to any neighborhood of any point on the hyperboloid.

Comment: You're on the right track. See my answer for a more explicit hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: What happens if you remove the origin from the cone? Well, if they were homeomorphic, you'd remove the corresponding point from the hyperboloid. Now what?

Comment: Oh....   I gave this answer about half a minute after you did.

Comment: Sorry, @WillJagy :)

Comment: Ah I see, they are not connected, so then they cannot be homeomorphic to each other. Thank you!

Comment: Be careful. One will be connected and the other will not.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the intersection of each of these surfaces with the plane $z=1.$

By moving that plane downward from $z=1$ to $z=0,$ you can shrink that loop on the cone down to a point. But there's no way to do that on the hyperboloid; it's not simply connected.

Comment: This is far fancier than necessary.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Perhaps, but a quick argument showing that there can be no image of the vertex of the cone under an homeomorphism didn't come to mind right away.